# How can I (/people using the package) start a Dash App that is inside an installed package?

Tags: python, python-import, plotly-dash

I'm developing a package that contains a module with a set of functions (fed3live.py) and another module that contains a Dash App (fed3_app.py). This is the structure of the package:

```
fed3live/
├─__init__.py
├─fed3live/
│ └─fed3live.py
| └─fed3_app.py
```

right now, the contents of my  `__init__.py` file are:

```
from .fed3live.fed3live import *
```

I would like to create a function in fed3live.py that can run fed3_app.py and launch the Dash App.
This is what I currently have in `fed3live.py`:

```
import pkg_resources
import runpy

def start_gui():
    """Starts the web-based FED3Bandit app
    """
    
    gui_loc = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'fed3_app.py')
    runpy.run_path(gui_loc, run_name='__main__')
```

This is kind of working, because when I call `start_gui()`, it does launch the app, but doesn't stay on. This is what I see on the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\fed3live>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\fed3live'; & 'C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Alex\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51628' '--' 'c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test_f3l.py' 
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app 'fed3_app'
 * Debug mode: on
C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe: No module named fed3_app
```

Where `test_f3l.py` is the script that calls `start_gui()` run from an environment that has the `fed3live` package installed.

Do you have any idea of why this might be happening? Additionally, if there are better ways of doing this, I'm willing to change things around. This is the best way I could think for starting a Dash App that is inside an installed package.

Comment: why not simply call `app.run_server` in your `start_gui()` function ? I'm not sure to get the question here, can you put a minimal example of what's in the `fed3_app.py` file ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! `fed3_app.py` would be any Dash App; nothing special here.
The function `start_gui()` is defined in `fed3live.py`. Sorry for not being clear enough, but does this make sense?

Comment: I did what you suggested @thmslmr and moved `start_gui()` to `fed3_app.py` and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know :) ! I move the comment to an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to start a Dash application (`app = Dash()`) is to call the `run_server()` method. You should be able to simply call this method from the `start_gui()` function.

```py
# fed3_app.py

app = Dash()
app.layout = ...

# your callbacks
```

```py
# fed3live.py
from fed3_app import app

def start_gui(..., server_kwargs: dict):
    app.run_server(**server_kwargs)
```